# Drop-down menu in Radcliffe theme

Tags: css

My page is https://visiapera.wordpress.com/ . I have been trying to make some changes in my drop-down menu but it does not seem to work.

I am trying to replace the red color when the mouse is over with white and just underline the word.
Then even though I make the text-align to left it does not align it to the left side of the main title. I will appreciate any suggestions...

```
.main-menu ul a {
  text-align: left;
  width: 170px;
  padding-left: 8%;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: 15%;
  border-top: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
```

In detail: 
If you go to the drop-down menu of the "design" title you will see that it is not aligned to the actual title (meaning the "design").
Then when the mouse goes over the drop-down menu it turns red and I do not want to have that (I only want it to be white).
I hope it is clear now as it is not possible to upload any photo...:(

Comment: Please add your CSS code in your question. If you can add a fiddle too it would be more helpfull.

Comment: .main-menu ul a {
 text-align: left;
 width: 170px;
 padding-left: 8%;
 padding-right: 0;
 margin-left: 15%;
 border-top: 1px;
 border-bottom: 1px;
 border-left: 0;
 border-right: 0;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}

nav > ul > li:hover > a {
 border-top: 1px solid #0a0a0a;
 text-decoration: none;
}

Comment: Sorry I saw I wrote "please add here". I meant that you please should edit your question and add it there as a formatted code

Comment: Try creating a demo that shows the actual issue.

Comment: Is it ok if I send a photo of the issue?

Comment: oops I cannot... My reputation is not that high... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To get the hover effect that you want:**

You should change:

`.main-menu ul a:hover {
    background: #ca2017 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-color: #ca2017;
    color: #fff;
}`

to something like:

`.main-menu ul a:hover {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: #fff;
}`

You may also want to remove the border radius from:

`.main-menu > li > a`, `.main-menu ul > li:first-child > a`, and `.main-menu ul > li:last-child > a`

**Your sub menu alignment issue is a bit of a mess.**

Your problems are from the negative left margins and the left positioning listed below (change them all to "0"):

`.main-menu ul {margin-left: -110px; /* change to 0 */}`

`.main-menu ul a {margin-left: 15%; /* change to 0 */}`

`.main-menu > li:hover > ul {left: 50%; /* change to 0 */}`

**To correct 3rd level sub menu alignment:**

Update the `margin-left` on your 3rd level menus to match the width of your 2nd level dropdown plus the additional space for the css arrow. It is currently 235px and should be 180px.

`.main-menu ul ul {margin-left: 180px; /* 170px ( width of .main-menu ul a) + 10px (CSS Arrow - .main-menu ul ul::after {left:-10px})}`